# Connecting to Oracle Database Using Python with cx_oracle

Tags: python, python-3.x, database-connection, cx-oracle

I am using cx_oracle to connect the Oracle DB using python.I need your assistance in connecting DB. I'm using following code till date it worked well

Code-1:

```
import cx_Oracle as cx
dsn_tns = cx.makedsn(HOST,PORT, service_name=SERVICE_NAME)
conn = cx.connect(user=USER, password=PW, dsn=dsn_tns)
```

Recently TCP port is disabled and we are using jdbc connection string to connect DB which has TCPS port number.can you help where I need to pass the protocol in above/ suggest any other method.

i tried following code

code-2:

```
dsn_tns='(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcps)(HOST =hostdetails)(PORT =port))) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = servicename)))'
conn = cx.connect(user=USER, password=PW, dsn=dsn_tns)
print(cx.version)
```

I got `error: ORA-28759: failure to open file`.

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you any one idea on this cx_Oracle.SUBSCR_PROTO_OCI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does your sqlnet.ora have a WALLET_LOCATION defined?

[Source](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-C0ECA1F5-7F91-4658-A927-F386E8B283D6).

Comment: I am able to connect the DB in SQl developer with connection string but not able to connect it using cx_oracle(python).

Comment: can you give me some inputs regarding WALLET_LOCATION?

Comment: See the [documentation link](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/dbseg/configuring-authentication.html#GUID-C0ECA1F5-7F91-4658-A927-F386E8B283D6) I provided.